# bind и this || JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this, контекст

Имеется следующий код:

```
function greet() {
  console.log('Greet', this);
}

let person = {
  name: "John",
  sayHi: greet,
  sayHiWindow: greet.bind(this)
}

person.sayHiWindow()
```

Возник вопрос: почему при вызове person.sayHiWindow() в консоли выдаёт объект window, а не person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут стоит помнить, что `this` равняется субъекту вызова метода, если упоминается внутри метода, в теле функции, в её области видимости. Когда вы определяете `sayHiWindow: greet.bind(this)`, вы присваиваете ключу `sayHiWindow` значение, возвращаемое функцией `greet.bind(this)`, и здесь `this` вы используете вне тела метода, как аргумент вызова функции, и вы находитесь в глобальной области видимости, где `this` равно `window`.

То, чего вы пытаетесь добиться, можно реализовать так:

```js
sayHiPerson : function() { greet.bind(this)(); },
```

Comment: если утрированно, то можно считать, что, скажем так, внутри объекта `person` `this` - это `window`, но внутри методов `this` равен объекту, в контексте которого он был вызван?

Comment: "внутри методов `this` равен объекту, в контексте которого он был вызван" — да, если никаких дополнительных аномалий (вроде `bind`) не было. "внутри объекта `person` `this` - это `window`" — не всегда: во-первых, «внутри объекта» — не очень чёткое понятие (внутри метода объекта это ведь тоже внутри объекта), но допустим мы имеет в виду определение ключей литерала объекта: тогда `this` будет `window` только вне контекста других методов и только в определённом окружении (в браузере); но если объект создаётся в области видимости другого метода, `this` уже может быть объектом окружающего метода.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в этом месте

```
sayHiWindow: greet.bind(this)
```

`this` - это `window`, а `person` еще не существует..

Comment: а из-за чего this - это window? где-то нашёл, что это за счёт, что this формируется при вызове функции, но если даже в функции greet сделать возврат строки, а в person указать не bind, а call, то всё равно получится ссылка на объект window. и в каком плане "person еще не существует"? вызов происходит после объекта person

Comment: @Pavel Я не понимаю, что Вы говорите. Какой возврат строки?

Comment: К примеру, если в функции greet будет не console.log, а, допустим, return 'Greet'.

Comment: @Pavel Я не понимаю, что Вы говорите. Покажите код.